# Is there a better way to structure a SQL table handling User Questionnaires?

Tags: sql

I have a disclosure form that requires a user to enter yes/no answers for a series of around 30 questions.

Is there a better way to create the table than having 30 columns that correspond the questions?

Below is my MS-SQL script, but the question relates more to structure than syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE Questionaire(
    QuestionaireID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    UserID int NOT NULL,
    Q1 bit NOT NULL,
    Q2 bit NOT NULL,
    Q3 bit NOT NULL,
    ... etc ...
    ... etc ...
    Q30 bit NOT NULL
)

-- and to store the questions relating to Q1, Q2, etc...
CREATE TABLE Questions(
    QuestionID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Question varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there are 2 better ideas i can think of:

1. store a vector (i.e. a string/byte array variable containing all results), and handle everything related to the data in your program (this way you're more limited on SQL queries)
2. store the key/value pair, keyed by survey-id, e.g.

   1134  age  68

   1134  prefer chocolate

   1134  width 6"

   1135  age  31

   1135  prefer vanilla

   1135  width 3.2"

it depends on what you want to do with the results.
but this is more "correct" than what you've suggested, since with my last option you're less likely to run into trouble

Comment: What is the benefit of reducing SQL usage? You've stated it as a given.

Comment: Thanks. I considered storing JSON / XML in a field, but reporting on that data would be tricky for me. All the questions have yes/no answers as mentioned and all the answers should be "no". Maybe the best approach would be to just store "notable" answers, ie where the user selects "Yes" to a question. Then ID, UserID, QuestionID would suffice?

Comment: This answer helped me come to the conclusion that I can get by nicely with just a Question table (QuestionID int, Question varchar(max)) and a Response table (ResponseID int, QuestionID int, UserID int, Response bit).

Comment: @Rex M -- i didn't understand your question. anyway, the SQL is not reduced, but with "vectored" data, it's more dificult to use conditional queries on individual fields (e.g. bit manipulations).  it's not impossible though.

Answer (score 4):

To fully normalize, you might want to consider a structure like this:

```
Table Questionaire(
    QuestionaireID...
    QuestionaireName...

Table Questions(
    QuestionaireID...
    QuestionID...
    QuestionName...

Table Response(
    QuestionaireID...
    ResponseID...
    UserID...

Table Answers(
    AnswerID...
    ResponseID...
    QuestionID...
    Answer...
```

This provides higher information fidelity, as you can capture data in more dimensions - at the response level, the individual answer level, as well as future-proofing yourself for changes to the system.

Comment: Should the Response table not link to QuestionID rather than QuestionaireID?

if Answers links to QuestionID, is QuestionaireID really necessary?

Is ResponseID in Answers the primary key, or a link to the Response table?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you want to re-use questions in different questionaires?
2. Do you want to have users be able to take more than one questionaire?
3. Do you ever want it to be anything but yes/no answers, like multiple choice?

If yes to all 3, I'd do it like this:

Table Questionaire(QuestionaireID, Name, Description)

Table Questions(QuestionID, Name)

Table QuestionResponses(QuestionResponseID, QuestionID, ResponseText)

Table QuestionaireQuestions(QuestionaireID, QuestionID)

Table UserQuestionaire(UserQuestionaireID, QuestionaireID, UserID)

Table UserResponses(UserQuestionaireID, QuestionResponseID)

Now you can define a list of questions, add them to one to many questionaires, they can have any number of responses, and users can log a questionaire and any responses they pick.

Comment: There's always a tradeoff between normalization vs. pragmatism in SQL. Your answer is highly normalised & would suit the three requirements you outlined, but is a bit of overkill in my situation. My usage is a user applying for a service. They must disclose yes/no to questions such as "are you a smoker", etc. It's strictly a 1-1 relationship between application & answer set and there has to be an answer for each question, so I initially thought to bundle 30 extra columns in the application table. After considering Berry Tsakala's answer I came to the conclusion mentioned in the comments there.